# Azure Pipelines error "TF401444: Please sign-in at least once as: ..."

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automation, azure-pipelines

I wanted to add a 'Create work item' step in a pipeline. It was supposed to be a creation of a bug ticket in case of the pipeline fail. I run the pipeline on my own VM, so I had to login to Azure and I wanted to use Service Principal for it:

`az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant>`

I believe this step worked fine, as I received a response (as visible on screenshot below). Next I was executing a command to create the bug ticket:

`az boards work-item create --organization https://dev.azure.com/my_org --project "Project" --type Bug --title "title" --description "desc" --output json --assigned-to ...`

At this point I constantly get an error:

`"TF401444: Please sign-in at least once as: credentials/of/tenant in a web browser to enable access to the service".`

[Screenshot of the execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yphk.png)

I already tried logging with my account credential

`az login -u mail -p psw`

and it works fine, and the bug ticket is created, but as you can guess I don't want to keep logging to Azure in pipeline with my login credentials.
I also tried using PAT for it, with a command:

`echo $(PAT) | az login`

but this required from me connecting to VM to log in to my account informing with a message:

`WARNING: A web browser has been opened at https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize. Please continue the login in the web browser. If no web browser is available or if the web browser fails to open, use device code flow with az login --use-device-code.`

After logging the bug ticket was also created, but I don't want to do this every execution, as the pipeline should be automated.

Do you have any idea how can I get rid of this error?

Or maybe you have any suggestions for better logging possibilities?

Comment: Hi swieckonrad; have you tried authenticating with the pipeline's own pat token? It is available as a [pre-defined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken) `$(System.AccessToken)`

Comment: Hi @VinceBowdren, when trying to use $(System.AccessToken), there appear the same message as in case of a PAT, so "WARNING: A web browser has been opened at...", so login is required anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Some workaround I found: you can use $(System.AccessToken) to log in using 'script' step in a pipeline instead of using AzureCLI.

```
- script: az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt
displayName: 'Allow extensions'
- script: echo $(System.AccessToken) | az devops login
displayName: 'Login to DevOps'
- script: |
    az boards work-item create --organization https://dev.azure.com/org --project "abc" --type Bug ...
displayName: 'Create a bug ticket'
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer your own question.  This was very helpful.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I needed to solve a problem I was having with the `az repos pr list` also.  Thanks!

Comment: Question - is there any way to save the output of that third script step? Trying to automate using the created item and struggling a bit

Comment: This solved my issue that I had for hours trying to use AzureCLI@2, it worked well before I started to mix in extensions. Logging on ad hoc with the access token and then running az with bash did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The "proper" way according to Azure docs is to set `System.AccessToken` in the `AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT` environment variable:

```yaml
# Using the script shortcut syntax
- script: az pipelines variable-group list --output table
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
  displayName: 'List variable groups using the script step'

# Using the task syntax
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: az pipelines variable-group list --output table
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
  displayName: 'List variable groups using the command line task'
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to fix the error by adding the Service Principal in the Azure DevOps user settings. The link is like:

https://dev.azure.com/< YOUR ORGANIZATION>/_settings/users

My case was the provisioning using Terraform. Here, the login information was written to environment variables (following input should be set "addSpnToEnvironment: true"). Sample of the Pipeline task:

```
#init and apply
- task: AzureCLI@2 
  displayName: "tf apply"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(serviceConnectionName)
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      #set conext by name as default / current subscription
      az account set --subscription $(platformManagemntSubscriptionId);
      
      #create variable
      $currentSubscription = $(az account list --query "[?isDefault].id" -o tsv)
      
      #create environment variables for terraform commands
      $env:ARM_CLIENT_ID       = $env:servicePrincipalId
      $env:ARM_CLIENT_SECRET   = $env:servicePrincipalKey
      $env:ARM_TENANT_ID       = $env:tenantId
      $env:ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = $currentSubscription
      
      #initialize 
      terraform init -backend-config="azurerm-vending-plattformresources.tfbackend";

      #apply
      terraform apply $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/platformresources/platformresources.tfplan;
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform/03_add_platformresources
```

Terraform doc to workitem resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/resources/workitem

Terraform to provider configuration(using env vars): https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/guides/authenticating_service_principal_using_a_client_certificate#provider-configuration