# Azure CLI task fails with TF401444: Please sign-in at least once as {tenantId} in a web browser to enable access to the service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I have two deploy pipelines under a DevOps project. One is for UI and other one is for API. The pipelines are confgured using yml files. And I have added a Azure CLI task to API deploy yml like this:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Create Rule For deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: "-Subscription_Here-"
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az network -Task_I_want _to _perform-'
```

And this task is working fine.
Now I was adding a similar Azure CLI task to my UI pipeline like this:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '-Subscription_Here-'
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az pipelines variable update --name APP_VERSION -value "$(APP_VERSION)" --pipeline-id $(System.DefinitionId) --org "$(System.CollectionUri)" --project "-Project_Name_Here-"'
```

Now the first task works fine in API pipeline works fine but the second task on UI pipline fails with

> TF401444: Please sign-in at least once as {tenantId} in a web browser to enable access to the service.

Although the Service Principal is same for both and both pipelines are under same project.

I was trying to update the pipeline variable value using the power shell script.

Comment: Maybe this can work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75544949/5233188

But I'm also searching for a better way.